# How to prove that the altitudes of the triangle are concurrent

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

Given a triangle of sides $A$ $B$ $C$ .how to prove that altitudes from sides $A$ $B$ $C$ are concurrent . There is a theorem called ceva's theorem.but i dont know how to use that theorem in this problem

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700740/three-altitudes-of-a-triangle-are-concurrent and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94096/altitudes-of-a-triangle-are-concurrent-using-co-ordinate-geometry and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255587/prove-concurrency-of-triangle-altitudes-with-vector-algebra

Comment: [Proof of the concurrency of the altitudes of a triangle](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMT668.Student.Folders/BrombacherAarnout/write-up%203.aarnout/orthocenterproof.html)

Comment: That make sense but i also dont know how to prove  the perpendicular bisectors of a triangle meet at a point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is slightly unclear. My way to interprete the request is: "Deliver a proof for the concurrence of the heights in a triangle by using the Theorem of Ceva". Here it is.

Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle, and let $D$, $E$, $F$ be on the sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$, so that $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are respectively perpendicular on these sides. In a picture:

[image: Concurrence of heights in a triangle]

The we have (without considering signs)
$$
\frac{DB}{DC}
=
\frac{DB}{DA}
\cdot
\frac{DA}{DC}
=
\frac{\cot B}{\cot C}\ .
$$
Now we build the *unsigned* product
$$
\frac{DB}{DC}\cdot
\frac{EC}{EA}\cdot
\frac{FA}{FB}
=
\frac{\cot B}{\cot C}\cdot
\frac{\cot C}{\cot A}\cdot
\frac{\cot A}{\cot B}\cdot
=
1\ .
$$
Let us now consider the signs. If $\Delta ABC$....

- has all angles $<90^\circ$, then each fraction above has negative sign, so the *signed* product is $-1$.
- has an angle $=90^\circ$, say the angle in $A$, then the heights are concurrent in $A$. This case is clear. (And the above computation does not really make sense.)
- has an angle $>90^\circ$, say the angle in $A$, then the heights from $B,C$ have the feet $E,F$ outside the side segments $CA$, $AB$, so the corresponding proportions have positive sign, the third proportion is negative.

We obtain (in the two unclear cases) the *signed* product
$$
\frac{DB}{DC}\cdot
\frac{EC}{EA}\cdot
\frac{FA}{FB}
=-1\ .
$$
The (reciprocal of the) Theorem of Ceva insures now $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ concurrent.